# Find the real function $f(x)$ if $f^{(n)}(0)$ is known

Tags: calculus

How to find the real function $f(x)$ if $f^{(n)}(0)$ is known? I have $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}.$$

What is the procedure for finding $f(x)$?

**EDIT:**

I want the closed form (generating function) of $f(x)$, and not given in $\sum$ notation.

My real problem is to examine the convergence and find the sum of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$, so I tried to reverse the steps. Here is what I have tried to find the sum:

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3!!}{2^2}\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{5!!}{2^3}\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\frac{x^n}{n!}+...$$
2. $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}$$
3. $f(x)=?$ where $f(x)$ should be expressed in the closed form (not in sigma notation).

I am stuck at step 3.

Comment: In a neighbourhood of $0$, if $f$ is real analytic, then it would be given by its Taylor series,  but you cannot say anything about any other point, and nothing at all if $f$ is non real analytic. Also, if $f(0)$ is not known (note that $f^{(0)}(0)$ does not make sense above) then even this cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no procedure without additional assumptions. Having all derivatives at a single point does not tell you the behavior of the function at any other point in general. For any given solution $f$, you can find a new solution $f'$ simply by changing its value at any finite set of point(s) $x$ where $x \neq 0$.

Comment: A little too restrictive answer. If the function under consideration is known to be analytic everywhere, then indeed having all derivatives (incl. of the zeroth) at a single point tells you the FULL behavior of the function at any other point. I admit that, clearly, the problem is to know in advance whether analytic behavior everywhere holds true, i.e. whether the convergence radius of the Taylor series is infinite.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, I said there is no procedure *without extra assumptions*.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the Taylor series

$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^nf^{(n)}(0)/n!
$

but, in your case, its radius of convergence may be zero.

Comment: What happens when the radius of convergence is zero? What is the procedure than?

Comment: Also, I want the closed form of function $f(x)$, and not given in $\sum$ notation.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n} \left( 2\,n-1
 \right) !!{x}^{n}}{ \left( 2\,n \right) !!}}= -1 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}},\qquad -1 < x \le 1 .
$$
But there are other functions with the same derivatives $f^{(n)}(0)$ as this one.  So the answer to your question (as asked) is what the others said: impossible.

**added**
Write
$$
u(x)=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n} \left( 2\,n-1
 \right) !!{x}^{n}}{ \left( 2\,n \right) !!}}
$$
(I added a sensible $n=0$ term.)  It has radius of convergence $1$.  You can differentiate term-by-term within the radius of convergence.  And doing that we can show that it satisfies the differential equation
$$
u(x) + 2(x+1)u'(x) = 0,\qquad u(0)=1
$$
Solve the differential equation.

**Another method** would be to recognize the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n} = \frac{(-1/2)(-3/2)(-5/2)\cdots(-(2n-1)/2)}{n!}
$$
in your formula.

Comment: But how did you even get this function?

Comment: Look at my edit in original post. It is the similar question.

Comment: How did you get that differential equation and binomial coefficient? How to use that binomial coefficient?